# PHP pcntl_fork() child processes and mysql queries

Tags: php, mysql

In my cli script, I start a lot of child processes, which do many operations on my mysql database in the runExport() method. (Edit:) Each process collects data from the db and writes it in its own CSV. (Edit end.)

When I look up the result CSV, only a few fields were filled. They are filled, wenn I remove the child process generation and run the script as a sequence. What is my mistake?

>

> ```
>    $list = new Productexportlist;
>    $list->selectString('SELECT * FROM productexports WHERE active = 1');
>
>    foreach ($list as $exporter) {
>        $pid = pcntl_fork();
>
>        if (!$pid) {
>            exporter->runExport();
>
>            exit;
>        }
>    }
> ```
>
> public function runExport()
>
> {
>
> ```
>     $productIds = $this->getExportProductIds();
>
>     // ... field formating methods
>
>     fputcsv($handle, $export, $this->getSeparator());
> ```
>
> }

Comment: So you have multiple process competing to write to same file?

Comment: No, each child process writes in its own csv

Comment: This isn't your exact real code I presume - you're missing a `$` on `exporter->runExport()`.

Comment: Would your 'many operations on the database' involve updates or inserts? If so then you need to use transactions when creating your CSV files. This will serialize access to the database. If the database isn't changing when generating the CSV files then i am not sure why they aren't complete. I assume that they report ALL errors including 'notices'.

Comment: There are only SELECTs and no notices. I'm using Adodb lite and have only a single db connection. Could there be concurrent queries disturbing each other?